# Какая польза от нескольких IP адресов для сайта

Tags: hosting

Облачный хостинг предлагает купить несколько IP адресов. Есть польза от покупки нескольких IP адресов для одного домена крупного проекта?

Comment: А sql-server предлагают в придачу, или почему на него метка?

Comment: Не знаю как от покупки, а вот от продажи кому-то польза точно есть:) А вообще хватай, пока предлагают. А то кричат скоро не останется красивых коротких 32-битных адресов, придёт покупать ужасные 128-битные.

Answer (score 1):

Только в том случае, если нужно обеспечить 2 или более endpoints, разнесенных на разные машины. Ну например может быть отдельно REST API и EPP API на разных машинах, или еще для каких-либо нужд. Это правда и по портам можно раскидать, но вот бывает что хочу отдельный IP, хочу и плачу, плачу и плАчу :)